# angular schematics generates blank lines in template, how to prevent it?

Tags: angular, blank-line, angular-schematics

I have ng schematics template `__name@dasherize__.component.html` with content :

> ```
> <% for (let row of getComponents().rows) { %>
> <div class="row">
>   <% for (let field of row.fields) { %>
>   <% if (field.type === 'InputString') { %>
>   <field labelCode="code" class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
>     <input name="code" ngModel [readonly]="readOnly">
>   </field>
>   <% } %>
>   <% } %>
> </div>
> <% } %>
> ```

I build it with :

```
npm run build 
schematics .:ui-generator --name=hello
```

Generated code creates empty lines on place where is put command "<%" in template, see:

> ```
> <div class="row">
>
>
>   <field labelCode="code" class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
>     <input name="code" ngModel [readonly]="readOnly">
>   </field>
>
>
>
>   <field labelCode="code" class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
>     <input name="code" ngModel [readonly]="readOnly">
>   </field>
>
>
>
>   <field labelCode="code" class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
>     <input name="code" ngModel [readonly]="readOnly">
>   </field>
>
>
>
>
> </div>
> ```

If I put schematics commands in template after html tags, like here :

```
<div class="row"><% for (let field of row.fields) { %><% if (field.type === 'InputString') { %>
      <field labelCode="code" class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
          <input name="code" ngModel [readonly]="readOnly">
      </field><% } %><% } %>
    </div><% } %>
```

then html is generated like it should be - without empty lines.

```
<div class="row">
  <field labelCode="code" class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <input name="code" ngModel [readonly]="readOnly">
  </field>
  <field labelCode="code" class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <input name="code" ngModel [readonly]="readOnly">
  </field>
  <field labelCode="code" class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <input name="code" ngModel [readonly]="readOnly">
  </field>
</div>
```

What do I wrong? Is is possible write schematic template command in "human readable" style? I mean in formatted style, or really must put command after html tags?

Comment: Good question, Have the same problem.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sadly no, I hope it will be fixed over time...